# Converting switched outlet to connect to recessed lights

Tags: wiring

I have limited electrical knowledge, I have a 4-way switched outlet in the hallway, and want to convert it to permanently hot, install recessed lights, and re-use the 4-way switches to power recessed lights.  I have figured out how to make switched outlet to permanently hot.
What I wanted to know was can I go into the attic and figure out the 4-way switch wires and just tap it to recessed light wiring or there is more to it.

Updated:  Here is link for images https://imgur.com/a/Z0ewv3r

Comment: Is running new wires an option?  Also, can you post photos of tthe insides of the existing boxes please?

Comment: Updated: Here is link for images https://imgur.com/a/Z0ewv3r